# Type of average that weighs larger numbers more?

Tags: average

I'm spreadsheeting my favorite albums and I'd like the good tracks on the album to count more for its average than the bad songs. I thought about geometric means, but those do the opposite of what I want.

Is my best course of action to raise each value to a certain number and then sum them and divide by some constant?

Comment: Yeah, you could choose some $\alpha>1$ and then calculate the quantity
$$
\left(\frac{1}{N} \sum_i x_i^{\alpha} \right)^{1/\alpha}
$$
where $x_i$ are the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generalized $p$-mean will do roughly what you want:

$$A_p = \left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N x_i^p\right)^{1/p}.$$

When $p=1$, you get the usual mean. The large $p$ you choose, the more the outliers will dominate the average (so that as $p\to\infty$, the album average approaches the maximum of the song scores.)